# Invalid input syntax , working with types in PostgreSQL how to pass correct input data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need your help please i am new to PostgreSQL and can't pass input values when it comes to inner arrays (employees,founder) in CompanyType .. Please some help with code example will be great !!

What correct syntax for passing the inner arrays within CompanyType argument ?

> > ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer:

```
SELECT companyRegistrationValidator
(
8768765765776,'TraderAnalytics','Trader.Analytics1988@gmail.com',
ARRAY
[
[76565445354, 'Maks', 'Burkov', 'Maks.Burkov88@gmail.com', '+_@Maks88'],
[6755465465, 'Yan', 'Burkov', 'Yan.Burkov1992@gmail.com', '+_@Yan92']
], -- First array for founders
ARRAY
[
[9878687687987,'Natali','Vladimirov','Natali.Burkov88@gmail.com','+_@Natali1990'],
[6546534365868,'Ludmila','Burkov','Malishka_Burkov988@gmail.com','-+Ludmila1965'],
[7656546546547,'Sasha','Burkov','Sasha_Burkov2018@gmail.com','+_@Sasha2018']
], -- Second array for employees
'Israel','@+Makspl88BS',3);


 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION companyRegistrationValidator (company CompanyType) RETURNS text[] AS $$

DECLARE
    r_firstname VARCHAR; r_lastname VARCHAR; r_email VARCHAR; r_password VARCHAR; r_country VARCHAR; r_comp_id VARCHAR;
    founder FounderType; employee EmployeeType;
    errors text []; counter SMALLINT = 0;

BEGIN

    SELECT email_r , password_r , country_r , firstname_r ,  lastname_r , id_r
        INTO r_email , r_password, r_country , r_firstname, r_lastname , r_comp_id FROM regex;

    IF company.comp_id::VARCHAR !~ r_comp_id THEN counter := counter + 1; errors [counter] := company.comp_id;
        ELSEIF  company.comp_name !~ r_firstname THEN counter := counter + 1; errors [counter] := company.comp_name;
          ELSEIF company.email !~ r_email THEN counter := counter + 1; errors [counter] := company.email;
                ELSEIF company.country !~ r_country THEN counter := counter + 1; errors [counter] := company.country;
                    ELSEIF company.c_password !~ r_password THEN counter := counter + 1; errors [counter] := company.c_password;
                        ELSEIF company.empl_number < 1 THEN counter := counter + 1; errors [counter] := company.empl_number;

    END IF;

FOREACH employee IN ARRAY company.employees LOOP

        RAISE NOTICE 'Employee data %',employee;

END LOOP;

FOREACH founder IN ARRAY company.founder LOOP

        RAISE NOTICE 'Founder data %',founder;

END LOOP;

RETURN errors;

 END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TYPE EmployeeType AS (
  emp_id BIGINT,
    firstname VARCHAR(150),
    lastname VARCHAR(150),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    e_password VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TYPE FounderType AS (
  founder_id BIGINT,
  firstname VARCHAR(150),
  lastname VARCHAR(150),
  email VARCHAR(50),
  f_password VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TYPE CompanyType AS (
comp_id BIGINT,
comp_name VARCHAR(50),
email VARCHAR(50),
founder FounderType [],
employees EmployeeType [],
country VARCHAR(50),
c_password VARCHAR(50),
empl_number INTEGER
);
```

Comment: Can you show the actual values you're calling the function with to get that error?

Comment: Yes here you go

Comment: OK. I don't have time to look into this much at the moment but basically the current error is due to casting that to your CompanyType type, the arrays in there start with a number and then contain text. PG thinks it's an array of integers so fails when it can't cast the following text to an integer. So you can either put the integers in your arrays in single quotes, or put an explicit cast to TEXT[] on the arrays. I tried that and got past that error, however when casting to your type it's complaining about something else, but as I said I don't have time to look into it further.

Comment: Looking forward to your help anyway , maybe tomorrow . 
I will try some new ways for passing too . Thanks!